# MySQL adapter gives an error

Tags: mysql, ruby

While trying to connect to Mysql using ruby, it throws an error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require

-bash-4.1$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
-bash-4.1$ gem list -i mysql
true
```

When I try the same code on a different server, it works. Any possible reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using `mysql2` gem. In fact, your regex should look like this precisely

```
gem list -i mysql
true
gem list -i ^mysql$ 
false
gem list -i ^mysql2$
true
```

So, use

```
require 'mysql2'
```

Comment: thanks for the reply; now when i Use 'mysql2' it throws a different error :  `<main>': uninitialized constant Mysql (NameError)

Comment: Well, even the constant, should be `Mysql2`

Comment: Read the gem documentation, please

Comment: Yes; I tried that and then it throws an error for that too                    
       undefined method `new' for Mysql2:   reading the gem documentation

Comment: Open another question. This one is solved and we have no sufficient information for the new one

Comment: Probably you need `Mysql2::Client.new`